# Updating same view from multiple controller actions - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, haml

My application has only one view page. My view page(oneview.haml) has the following flow.

1. Initially it contains only form with a submit button. This is loaded with the default controller action oneview(which loads the intial oneview.haml).
2. Once the user fills the form and clicks submit I have to invoke a new controller action and perform an API call with the form details and the returned data has to be updated on the same view(oneview.haml). The oneview.haml shouldn't be reloaded it has to be updated without a refresh. Let this be a table with some clickable rows.
3. If the user clicks on one of the rows a new controller action has to invoked. and this controller also perfroms some api call depending upon the passed parameters from the clickable row and add a new div has to be added to the same page with the details of the row. Here also the page shouldnt be reloaded but has to updated by adding an extra div.

I am kind of new to rails and havent dealt with ajax before. I know the dynamic loading and all deals with ajax. But my point here is how can the different controller actions update an already existing view. I know from controller render we can make pages load, but how can we add contents to an already existing page fron different controller actions.

I know its a long question and I am kind of stuck on this for few days. Any help and references will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most basic references can be found at the JQuery site for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

It sounds like you wish to bind an on click event to a DOM element that will run an ajax call, and then use the data passed via said call to do something on your page.

Simple on click binding:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function() {
    //AJAX call
});
```

Sample AJAX call and [Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "methodUrl",
    success: function (returnedData) {
    //Do stuff with returnedData, for example appending html type data
    $("selector").append(returnedData);
    }
});
```

You can add error handling, POST data to your backend as parameters for your method, return a different data type than what you send (using contentType for sending data and dataType for receiving data) and various other customizable options depending on what exactly you need to do.

In general AJAX is a great way to hit your server and manipulate objects and your page without sending a complete page reload request.

Comment: Thanks for the ajax suggestion. But mainly i am looking for the suggestions from rails side how to handle one view page from multiple controller actions

Comment: Using URL in the ajax call you can hit any method in your backend. Then use multiple ajax calls to hit different endpoints.